# Passport login - mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, passport.js

I am having some issues with a passport login using mysql. Here is my code:

```
    /*jshint esversion: 6 */
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const db = require('../config/db');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

module.exports = function(passport) {

  // =========================================================================
  // passport session setup ==================================================
  // =========================================================================

  // used to serialize the user for the session
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  // used to deserialize the user
  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', [id], function(err, rows) {
      done(err, rows[0]);
    });
  });

  // Local Strategy login
  passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {

    // Match Username
    let sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?';
    db.query(sql, [username], function(err, rows) {
      if (err)
        return done(err);
      if (!rows.length) {
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Wrong user'});
      }

      //  Match Password
      bcrypt.compare(password, rows[0].password, function(err, isMatch) {
        if(err)
          return done(err);
        if(isMatch){
          return done(null, rows[0]);
        } else {
          return done(null, false, {message: 'Wrong pass'});
        }
      });
    });
  }));
};
```

> Cannot POST to /user/login

no other errors are logged, this is weird, because I've set it up to where it should work, as my register is set-up the exact same way, so I am going to give snippets of all my code to give an idea so first the snippets from main file:

```
// Passport config
require('./config/passport')(passport);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// User Route
let user = require('./routes/reg');
app.use('/user', user);
```

Okay now the stuff actually in the reg.js file for the login route.

```
// Login Process
router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    sucessRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/',
    failureFlash: true,
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

And now the actual form that POST's to it:

```
    <form method="POST" action="/user/login">
      <h3><label>Username:</label></h3><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" /><br>
      <h3><label>Password:</label></h3><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" /><br>
      <br><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"><a href="#" style="font-size: 12px;">  Lost Password?</a>
    </form>
```

UPDATE: It seems if the login is wrong, it does everything right, however if the login is correct, it does the "`Cannot POST /user/login`", so I'm assuming it is something to do with my line:

```
return done(null, rows[0]);
```

Which doesn't exactly surprise me, however I am clueless on as to why it is doing this.

Okay I'm convinced that it is not serializing the user. Which I have been looking up, but can't find anything.

Comment: I know 100% it is now doing this on a correct login, as I've made a different message rather than trying to pass it as it now. so it is "return done(null, rows[0]);" however I still have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong, looking through all these tutorials and guides it seems I am doing everything right, but obviously I'm missing something.

Comment: do you mean that if login is wrong it redirects to login page?

Comment: What's the status code?  Also, it could possibly be a problem with `serializeUser`.

Comment: There is no status code, it just says "Cannot POST /user/login" and @chirag, it works if it is wrong, ill give the message and redirect to my failing page (which happens to be the homepage). serializeUser seems to be the same no matter where I look, be it mysql or with mongoDB, I know it has something to do ti with it, im just not sure what, i can debug it better at home as the console on my laptop keeps failing the connection

Comment: there's almost certainly a status code, you can see it from the Network tab of your browser's developer tools :)

Comment: it's a 404. I'm guessing somehow the route is wrong, but ive triple checked the route, (it's fail redirects wouldn't work if it wasn't found to begin with). Also, if I change the line to "return done(null, false, {message: 'Login Success!'});" it shows the message just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a problem in Login process.

You can use `authenticate()` function as route middleware to authenticate requests. Like this:

```
router.post('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

Comment: At a glance removing next probably wouldn't do anything as the function is working. It is only when  successful login occurs that I get this problem. If this were the issue, it would have done it for all other scenarios (Wrong username and/or password.) I can;t test it right now, but I think I'll get the same problem, or a whole new one.

Comment: As I suspected removing next broke it. (not sure the exact error, though, as I just did it quickly at work).

Comment: oh! man! `next` is not an issue. but the spelling mistake `successRedirect` is wrong in your code everthing else is good. i need to edit my answer.

Comment: *sighs* One little c gave me a days headache. I don;t think my brain is used to finding simple problems like this. I read them correctly, like my brain "auto corrects", it's slighty infuriating at this point. Thank you very much!